# Win10: Cannot get both displays to turn off

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, power-management

I have a Windows 10 desktop system with two monitors and I cannot get the monitors to turn off correctly. I've already tried working with MS tech support, but they weren't terribly useful.

I currently have my advanced power settings (from Control Panel> Hardware & Sound > Power Options > Advanced Settings) set as follows:

- Turn off display after: 1 minute
- Console lock display off timeout: 3 minutes

The secondary monitor is daisy-chained to the primary (via Display port), and the primary is connected to a discrete Nvidia GTX 1050. The monitors are recent (<1 year old) Dell displays. It's a home-built system with a modern Core i7-7700K and Asus motherboad. Updated to latest OS version.

Problems:

1. Despite whatever settings I have, my primary monitor will always stay on. Both at the lock screen and in Windows.
2. My secondary display stays on while in Windows. But when I log out to the lock screen, it goes blank (correctly).

My goal here is to get the monitors to correctly turn off in Windows and to correctly turn off at the lock screen so that they do not burn out.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you disconnect the secondary display? Does it work correctly in Safe Mode? Does it work if you disconnect all input devices?

Comment: If I disconnect the second monitor, then everything works fine. So perhaps it's a problem with the daisy-chaining?

Comment: Sounds probable. Not sure if you can try connecting the secondary monitor first and daisy-chain from it to the primary...and have a positive effect.